# two separate handlers for logging of grails app and src/groovy files

Tags: spring, grails, logging, groovy, logback

I have a grails app and some other classes in src/groovy and would like to print out the debug logs on my console by using the annotation `@Slf4j` on my groovy files.

The problem is that it prints out all debug information, from the apache server and spring framework etc and it is impossible to see what has been printed. Can I somehow send a parameter to `$Sl4j(type="simple")` and then check if parameter is set then print out debug information else only print errors?

This is my current setup that prints out to much debug information:

src/groovy/ExampleClass.groovy

```
@Slf4j
class ExampleClass {
        def test(){
                log.debug "The test is printed"
        }
}
```

grails-app/conf/logback.groovy

```
import grails.util.BuildSettings
import grails.util.Environment


// See http://logback.qos.ch/manual/groovy.html for details on configuration
appender('STDOUT', ConsoleAppender) {
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        pattern = "%level %logger - %msg%n"
    }
}

root(ERROR, ['STDOUT'])
root(DEBUG, ['STDOUT'])

if(Environment.current == Environment.DEVELOPMENT) {
    def targetDir = BuildSettings.TARGET_DIR
    if(targetDir) {

        appender("FULL_STACKTRACE", FileAppender) {

            file = "${targetDir}/stacktrace.log"
            append = true
            encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
                pattern = "%level %logger - %msg%n"
            }
        }
        logger("StackTrace", ERROR, ['FULL_STACKTRACE'], false )
    }
}
```